# Alternative to looping InputStream#read

Tags: java, url, nio, channel, fileoutputstream

The NIO api contains some very neat solutions for data transfer. Methods that saves input streams as files to a hard drive via channels and files that are loaded directly from the hard drive into the RAM. There's however no neat solution I could find that loads input streams directly into the RAM. The only solution I could think of is looping trough the input stream. That's why I was wondering if there was an alternative to this method.

A `Channel` solutions I admire:

```
URL url = new URL(name);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

Comment: Th code you 'admire' doesn't work. You have to call the transfer methods in a loop. They aren't guaranteed to transfer the entire requested size without fail. That's why they have return values.